# Как найти цитаты в непарных (“” и «») кавычках с помощю регулярных выражений?

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужно просто найти цитаты, в тексте. Действительно всё, при чём не известно что это будет за текст вообще.
Моего гения хватило на такую регулярку:

```
([“”]|[«»]|["]){1}.{2,}?\1
```

И она работает, но только с обычными кавычками, а вот как сделать с остальными?

Для примера:

**"Отдохнул - во! Сметаны - во! Рыбы - во!"**
«Прилетаю я на Таити… А вы не были на Таити?»
“Гаити, Гаити… Не были мы ни в какой Гаити!
Нас и здесь неплохо кормят.”
**"Роди-и-ительский дом… Нача-а-ало начал…"**

Comment: где будет выполняться эта регулярка?

Comment: На столе у препода, лол

Comment: и какой диалект регулярок он будет использовать при проверке?

Comment: А какой диалект реализован в модуле re в Python 3.6?

Comment: Добавь в вопрос примеры строк, к которым ты применял указанную регулярку, ожидаемый результат и результат который получаешь сейчас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение какое-то топорное, но вот что я придумал:

```
r'(".{2,}?"|“.{2,}?”|«.{2,}?»)'
```

с флагом `re.DOTALL`  в случае с Python